# How to do return array or list<string> Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a function with store procedure entity framework, i want to return as JSON string .

```
public static string GetGroupModFunc(string group_mod_id)
    {

        var idParam = new SqlParameter
        {
            ParameterName = "GID",
            Value = group_mod_id
        };
        var obj= db.Database.SqlQuery<string>("EXEC GET_GROUP_PERMIT @GID", idParam).FirstOrDefault();
        string json = "";
        return json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
    }
```

Thank guys.

Comment: You having any kind of error?

Comment: Hi sir, as you see, I want to return list or array , which hold the result of query.

Comment: if you want a list, then why are you using `FirstOrDefault()`?

Comment: Ok sir, because after run query with store procedure , the result have one row .

Comment: I try `ar obj = db.Database.SqlQuery<string>("EXEC GET_GROUP_PERMIT @GID", idParam).ToList();
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);` . It's error `System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: The data reader has more than one field. Multiple fields are not valid for EDM primitive or enumeration types.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for this issue: load data from database to a DataTable, then convert the data from DataTable to JSON.